# Cypress wait-until plugin issue: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code

Tags: cypress, cypress-wait-until

I've got this helper function that is supposed to wait until status equals 'SENT'.

```js
function waitForSENTStatusDB(GWuuid: string) {
        cy.log("wait for status 'SENT' in DB");
        cy.waitUntil(() => {
            const BodyToUse = "SELECT * FROM table where entity_id = '{GWID}' order by last_modified_at desc".replaceAll("{GWID}", GWuuid);

            DB.Generic(BodyToUse).then((res) => {
                let status = res[0].status;
                cy.log("Current status: " + status);
                return status === INTERFACES.UploadStatus.SENT;
            });
            }, {
                errorMsg: "Timeout: Upload status is not 'SENT'",
                interval: 10000,
                timeout: 200000
            }
            )
        }
```

I'm calling the function in an 'it' block in Cypress:

```js
it(`(Iteration: config changed = ${item.PAYLOAD_CHANGE.configurationChanged})Check/Wait for entity state - status SENT (via DB)`, () => {
            waitForSENTStatusDB(GWid);
        });
```

The function is waiting properly and everything but once I the helper function returns `true` to move on to the next `it` block, Cypress gives me the following error during execution:

```
cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: true
```

I'm new to Cypress, I tried everything that came to my mind.

After the helper function with waitUntil() returns true, the execution will move on to the next it block.

Comment: Every *it* is a separate test, so this one should have an assert somewhere at the end. Because currently you are returning true and do not use it.
I'd make this a custom command, with an assertion in then().
That should also solve the mentioned issue about mixing async and sync code.

Answer (score 4):

The waituntil command is limited, but you can substitute a plain javascript function to repeat the command.

Since you already wrap with a function, add a counter to the parameters and repeat call if the condition is not met.

```js
function waitForSENTStatusDB(GWuuid, times: 0) {

  cy.log("wait for status 'SENT' in DB", times);

  if (times > 20) {    // counter = timeout/interval
    throw new Error("Timeout: Upload status is not 'SENT'")
  }

  const bodyToUse = `SELECT * FROM table where entity_id = '${GWuuid}' order by last_modified_at desc`

  DB.Generic(bodyToUse).then((res) => {
    let status = res[0].status;
    cy.log("Current status: " + status)

    if (status !== INTERFACES.UploadStatus.SENT) {
      cy.wait(10000)
      waitForSENTStatusDB(GWuuid, ++times)
    }
}


waitForSENTStatusDB('123')
```

Comment: Yeah, actually the reason why I didn't use a recursive function is because of memory limitations in Gitlab.

Comment: `waitUntil` is using recursion, with heavier footprint than plain javascript, but is less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using the cy.log function within the waitUntil. Don't ask me for technical reasons, but simply substituting it with console.log helped.